# Mean and Variance of probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-theorem

I know how to calculate mean and variance of some given numbers but I have trouble computing them for probability distributions especially when it is a continuous probability distribution.
For example, can you show me how to calculate mean and variance of Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Are you having trouble writing down the appropriate integrals or computing them?

Comment: Writing down the appropriate integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E[X]=\int xf_X(x)\mathrm dx\qquad E[X^2]=\int x^2f_X(x)\mathrm dx$$ $$\mathrm{var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$$